# Tizen Gear S: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 - Websockets

Tags: dom, websocket, tizen, securityexception, gears

I am using Websockets to implement the MQTT protocoll in Tizen on a Samsung Gear S. While everything works fine in the IDE emulator I always get an SecurityError: DOM Exception  18 when running it on the watch.

Access origin is set:

```
    <access origin="http://broker.hivemq.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://broker.hivemq.com:8000" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://broker.hivemq.com:1883" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
    <access origin="http://test.mosquitto.org" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://test.mosquitto.org:1883" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://test.mosquitto.org:8080" subdomains="true"/>
   <tizen:content-security-policy>connect-src http://www.heartxxx.bt&#xD; ...  http://broker.hivemq.com;&#xD;</tizen:content-security-policy>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Anything I missed?
Thanks for help!

Klemens

Here the MQTT Code used. Is uses the JavaScript library mqttws31.ja von IBM (basically PAHO)

```
var client = null;
var topic = "sensor";
var qos = 2;

var options =
{

    // connection attempt timeout in seconds
    timeout : 3,

    // Gets Called if the connection has successfully been established
    onSuccess : function()
    {
        $("#mqttout").append("mqttconnect: Connected" + "<br />");

        /*
         * client.subscribe(topic, { qos : qos });
         * 
         */

        client.subscribe("adl",
        {
            qos : qos
        });

    },

    // Gets Called if the connection could not be established
    onFailure : function(message)
    {
        $("#mqttout").append(
                "mqttconnect: Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage
                        + "<br />");
    }

};

function mqttclear()
{
    $("#mqttout").empty();
}

var isens = 0;

// Host: broker.hivemq.com
// Port: 1883
// Websocket Port: 8000

// Host: test.mosquitto.org
// Port: 1883
// Websocket Port: 8080
var mqttservers = [
{
    "server" : "broker.hivemq.com",
    "port" : 1883,
    "webport" : 8000
},
{
    "server" : "test.mosquitto.org",
    "port" : 1883,
    "webport" : 8080
},
{
    "server" : "192.168.2.113",
    "port" : 1883,
    "webport" : 8000
}];

var mqttserver = "broker.hivemq.com";
var mqttwebport = 8000;

function setmqttserver(i)
{
    mqttdisconnect();
    mqttserver = mqttservers[i].server;
    mqttwebport = mqttservers[i].webport;

    for (var ij = 0; ij< mqttservers.length; ij++)
    {
        $("#mq"+ij).css("background-color", "red");
    }
    $("#mq"+i).css("background-color", "green");
}

function mqttconnect()
{
    // Connect to Public Broker

    try
    {
        client = new Messaging.Client(mqttserver,
                mqttwebport, "clientId_"
                        + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

        client.connect(options);

        client.onMessageArrived = function(message)
        {
            isens++;
            $("#mqttout").append(
                    "onMessageArrived: " + isens + " Topic: "
                            + message.destinationName + '  | '
                            + message.payloadString + "<br />");
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        $("#mqttout").html("mqttconnect: Error - " + e.message);
    }
}

function mqttpublish(num)
{
    try
    {
        num = num || 1;
        $("#mqttout").append("publish: Testdata sent" + "<br />");
        if (client != null)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                var act = "A";
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    act = "G";
                var sensdata = act + ";" + new Date().getTime() + ";"
                        + Math.random() * 10 + ";" + Math.random() * 10 + ";"
                        + Math.random() * 10 + ";";
                var message = new Messaging.Message(sensdata);
                message.destinationName = topic;
                message.qos = qos;
                client.send(message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mqttout").append("publish: Not connected" + "<br />");
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        $("#mqttout").html("mqttpublish: Error - " + e.message);
    }
}

function mqttdisconnect()
{
    try
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.disconnect();
            $("#mqttout").append("mqttdisconnect: Disconnected" + "<br />");
            client = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mqttout").append("mqttdisconnect: Not connected" + "<br />");
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        $("#mqttout").html("mqttdisconnect: Error - " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding specific origin..try adding this in your config.xml file <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>

Comment: Thanks! Tried it, no effect.

Comment: Do you mind sharing sample code?